# Programmatically set UIBarButtonItem fill color?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I have a set of UIBarButtonItems from png files inside a UIToolbar.

When a user clicks on an icon, I want that icon to be filled with a color to indicate a state change.

Is it possible to do this with a single set of images (maybe by programmatically changing some attributes) or do I necessarily need two sets of images (on for each state) ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your `UIImage`'s renderingMode is `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` first

if you initWithImage then change `UIBarButtonItem`'s tintColor.

> Although UIBarButtonItem is not a view, its tintColor property behaves
>   the same as that of UIView.

else if you initWithCustomView in which with a `UIImageView` then change the imageView's tintColor might work too

else you can setItems: animated:NO to `UIToolBar` every time after clicks which might not be a elegant one

Answer (score 0):

It is very straight forward. You just need to do the following in code :

```
imgView.image = [imgView.image
    imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
imgView.tintColor = [UIColor someColor];
```